# Custom Discriminator on base type = null: "but does not have a discriminator value configured"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I'd like to implement a TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) with a custom Discriminator. Here are the models:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
public class Appointment : Event
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

My custom Discriminator should be the `Duration` column: If it's `NULL` than it must be an `Event`, otherwise an `Appointment`.

But I get this error on creating the migration step:

> The entity type 'Event' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured.

What did I wrong? And how can I get the Discriminator up and running?

---

Here's the `DbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasDiscriminator<TimeSpan?>(nameof(Appointment.Duration))
            .HasValue(null)
            ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is originally because that the value of a *Discriminator* cannot be null. But Actually there is another problem that makes it not work.
Every entity type in TPH (`Event` and `Appointment`) must have a property as *Discriminator*. 
If you don't specify any configuration for *Discriminator*, a property named *Discriminator* with type of string is used by default. This property stores name of the entity type and is used to examine what type a row maps to.
You can either leave the configuration of *Discriminator* (to the default behavior) or configure a custom one like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
public class Appointment : Event
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasDiscriminator<int>("discriminator")
            .HasValue<Event>(1)
            .HasValue<Appointment>(2);
    }
}
```

Note: if type of *Discriminator* is not string, then for each entity type in hierarchy, a discriminator value must be specified. (as shown in above code) 
But If type of *Discriminator* is string, then it can be automatically filled with entity type name.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
        .HasValue("e"); // "e" is the value of discriminator for Event type. 
        // we don't need to specify another value for Appointment type. it defaults 
        // to "Appointment"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Assuming I introduce a property of `enum EventType`, is something like this possible: `.HasDiscriminator(e => e.Type).HasValue<Event>(e => e.Type <= EventType.Deadline).HasValue<Appointment>(e => e.Type >=
 EventType.Interview)`

Comment: no you can't use it like this. actually I think the code you have written won't even compile. see this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance)